# Google Analytics - Track users questionnaire scores

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, analytics

I'm building a questionnaire where the user completes a set of multiple choice questions which eventually scores them into one of three categorises - low/medium/high.

A click event on a 'Get score' button stores the user score into a js variable.

Is there anyway i can track (using google analytics) how many users scored under each of these categories? Would i need to use custom variables for this?

Sami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There many ways to go about this. You can set the results directly with analytics.js tracking object or you can use the data import feature to map an anonymous user id and the responses. Either way you will first need to create a [user scoped custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user#dimensions) in which you store the user categories. And you can either [send in the custom dimension with the hit information](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1': 'low'
});
```

Where dimension1 maps to the index of the user scoped custom dimension you created.

To set the user id and upload a user category you can set the user id in the tracker creation step.

```
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

And then upload a file maps the user id to the response.

```
ga:userId,ga:dimension1
1234,'low'
1235,'high'
1236,'low'
1237,'medium'
```

Again where ga:dimension1 maps the user scoped custom dimensions you created to represent the category and the ga:userId maps to the user id you set in the tracker creation step.

This article on [importing CRM user information to create AdWords remarketing](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user) lists spells out yet another approach if you need to map many "user" representations to any number of categories.

Comment: Thanks Matt, big help.